# WebView Open '_blank' Links

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview

I have a WebView which loads content from the Internet.
If I have a link which uses the '_blank' attribute, nothing happens.

So far I have tried setting my WebView delegate but I can't get it to register, I can't even get an NSLog back so I must be using it wrong. The code is as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [tmpView setUIDelegate:self];
}

- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"HEY THERE");
    return sender;
}
```

Ideally what I'd like, is that whenever a link is clicked on a WebView, the link is always opened within that WebView, nowhere else.

Is this possible?

Through research I found other methods but have no idea how to use them to get the result I desire:

```
webView:decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:request:newFrameName:decisionListener:
```

I'm completely stumped so I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: this might help: http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/

Comment: @hanumanDev, that won't help because it's an article about the iOS `UIWebView` and the question is about the Mac `WebView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to open a new window but just open the request in your current `WebView` object, you just need to do this in your delegate:

```
- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    [[sender mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
    return sender;
}
```

Comment: this is EXACTLY what i was looking for, i just don't know how to link the delegate? Do i draw the arrow from the WebView to the File Owner from FrameLoadDelegate?

Comment: the reason I ask is because at the moment this method doesn't seem to get executed? thanks again Rob

Comment: That method is part of the `WebUIDelegate` protocol, so you need to assign whichever object implements the method as the `UIDelegate` of the `WebView`. In your example code you have implemented it in the App Delegate, so you would link the `UIDelegate` outlet of the `WebView` to the `AppDelegate` object.

Comment: Alternatively, if your app delegate has an outlet to the web view, you can call `[webView setUIDelegate:self]` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Comment: you absolute hero, it works! i've been trying to do this for hours AAAH. Thanks SO much !

Answer (score 1):

This blog post provides a solution using JavaScript to basically remove the target attribute from links.

http://blog.mikeweller.com/2009/06/uiwebview-doesnt-open-targetblank-links.html

Comment: when tested on Chrome this does indeed remove all the bad attributes, exactly what I want, however the code doesn't seem to be doing anything to my WebView? I've put it in the WebViewProgressFinished method but the links still can't be clicked?

Answer (score 0):

you can call

```
(WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

it did work.

you can also implement

```
(void)webView:(WebView *)sender decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
```

to do what you want to achieve.